# raid 0 recovery after accidental dd to disk

Tags: data-recovery, dd, data, system-recovery

I have 3 HDD's: `/dev/sda` and  `/dev/sdb` (2x1TB) both on RAID 0 mode -> `/dev/md127`, and 4TB `/dev/sdc`, -> `/dev/sdc`.

Accidentally I ran `dd` script from https://github.com/tdg5/blog/blob/master/_includes/scripts/dd_obs_test.sh to `/dev/md127` (script wrote 134218752 bytes (128MB) to raid), where is my linux OS.

Is there any chance to recover everything, system is nor restarted yet and displaying errors, cannot use 99% of commands, here is the log from console:

```
[root@ns2 tmp]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.8G  4.0K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.8G  624K  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md127       64Z   64Z  677G 100% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /tmp
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/509
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
[root@ns2 tmp]# df -a
Filesystem                1K-blocks                 Used Available Use% Mounted on
sysfs                             0                    0         0    - /sys
proc                              0                    0         0    - /proc
devtmpfs                    8162264                    4   8162260   1% /dev
securityfs                        0                    0         0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs                       8169748                   12   8169736   1% /dev/shm
devpts                            0                    0         0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs                       8169748                  596   8169152   1% /run
tmpfs                       8169748                    0   8169748   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/pstore
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup                            0                    0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
configfs                          0                    0         0    - /sys/kernel/config
/dev/md127     73786976294807425856 73786976294098109944 709299528 100% /
hugetlbfs                         0                    0         0    - /dev/hugepages
tmpfs                       8169748                    0   8169748   0% /tmp
systemd-1                         -                    -         -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
debugfs                           0                    0         0    - /sys/kernel/debug
mqueue                            0                    0         0    - /dev/mqueue
tmpfs                       1633952                    0   1633952   0% /run/user/509
tmpfs                       1633952                    0   1633952   0% /run/user/0
binfmt_misc                       0                    0         0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
[root@ns2 tmp]# hdparm --help
-bash: /usr/sbin/hdparm: Structure needs cleaning
[root@ns2 tmp]# w
-bash: /usr/bin/w: Structure needs cleaning
[root@ns2 tmp]# ps
-bash: /usr/bin/ps: Structure needs cleaning
[root@ns2 tmp]# top
-bash: top: command not found
[root@ns2 tmp]# dnf --help
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Aborted
[root@ns2 tmp]# yum --help
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: Input/output error
[root@ns2 tmp]# kill --help
-bash: kill: -help: invalid signal specification
[root@ns2 tmp]# who
-bash: who: command not found
[root@ns2 tmp]# w
-bash: /usr/bin/w: Structure needs cleaning
[root@ns2 tmp]# xfs_copy
-bash: xfs_copy: command not found
[root@ns2 tmp]# ls -la /dev/sdc1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 33 Jun  4 17:53 /dev/sdc1
[root@ns2 tmp]#
```

EDIT:
SO i've booted from live CD, DD'ed my RAID 0 -> /dev/md127 to /dev/sdc1 as raid.img and running xfs_repair -n now. i'm pretty new with this is there any other command to fix it with as low damage as it possible?

Comment: All recovery operations would of course need to be run on the raid array and not on the actual disk partitions.

Comment: Such a devastating attack you did to your filesystem will obviously require you to reinstall everything, but you may be lucky enough to recover most of your configuration and personal files if you put enough time and effort into it.

Comment: I'd make an image of the damaged filesystem and try my luck with `testdisk`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no redundancy in raid0, so whatever you have overwritten is gone.

Comment: Actually, the RAID level is pretty much irrelevant in this case as he wrote to the array and not to a single disk. Even if you had e.g. a RAID1 with redudant disks, these changes would have been written to both disks at once; RAID can't protect you from cases like these.

Comment: Right, I didn't get that far into analysing the situation.